# The type or namespace 'frombody' could not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, api

I am encountering an error related to `formbody`. I am creating a `CRUD REST API` in `dot net`. Below is the code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using ProductDataAccess;

public ProductEntities Entities = new ProductEntities();

 public HttpResponseMessage Post([FormBody] Product product)
    {
        try
        {
            Entities.Products.Add(product);
            Entities.SaveChanges();
            var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, product);
            response.Headers.Location = Request.RequestUri;

            return response;
        }
         catch (Exception)
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Data Not Inserted");

        }
    }
```

**Update 1**

The `ProductDataAccess` file is created as a new project but both are under same solution. The code for the controller is below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using ProductDataAccess;

namespace REST_API.Controllers
{
   public class ProductsController : ApiController
   {
    public ProductEntities Entities = new ProductEntities();

    public HttpResponseMessage Get()
    {
        try
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Found, Entities.Products.ToList());
        }
        catch
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "No Data Found");
        }
    }

    public HttpResponseMessage Get (int id)
    {
        try
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Found, Entities.Products.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Id == id));
        }
        catch
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "No Data Found");
        }
    }

    public HttpResponseMessage Post([FormBody] Product product)
    {
        try
        {
            Entities.Products.Add(product);
            Entities.SaveChanges();
            var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, product);
            response.Headers.Location = Request.RequestUri;

            return response;
        }
         catch (Exception)
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Data Not Inserted");

        }
    }
}}
```

Here I am getting `formbody` error. I got one [answer](https://forums.asp.net/t/2120454.aspx?The%20type%20or%20namespace%20name%20FromBody%20could%20not%20be%20found%20are%20you%20missing%20a%20using%20directive%20or%20an%20assembly%20reference%20) to the question but still, i am unable to get the desired results.

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: Functions and definitions directly on the file without namespace nor class?

Comment: @Gusman the namespaces are added. The `ProductDataAccess` file was created separately and was added as a reference in the API project. But both files are under same solution

Comment: Again, in that file there's no namespace nor class. If the example is malformed then add the real code, else that code is completely wrong.

Comment: @Gusman kindly see the updated code

Comment: Ok, it's not `FormBody`, it's `FromBody`...

Comment: Does that mean it's resolved?

Answer (score 2):

Import the following namespace:

```
using System.Web.Http;
```

If you're using dot-net-core, then import the following one

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
```

Answer (score 0):

**FormBody** has to be **FromBody** The action filter lets the method know that the variable object has to be populated with the data in the request.

Example JSON object in the body of a POST request to your API:

```
{
  "Name" : "Product Name",
  "Price" : 0.50 
}
```

API Method that takes the request body and parses to the C# object:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] Product product)
{
   var name = product.Name; // "Product Name"
   var price = product.Price: // 0.50
}
```

Cheers!